# What encryption method is my BitLocker encrypted drive using?

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

Is there a way to find out what encryption method and cypher strength my BitLocker encrypted drive is using?

I'm running on an up to date version of Windows 10 but I can't remember how long ago I encrypted the drive or what settings I selected at the time.

When I open the "Manage BitLocker" settings, the only info I can see is which drives are encrypted, but there doesn't seem to be a way of seeing what the current encryption settings are.

This is for a "BitLocker To Go" external drive (though it would be good to know how to check for an internal drive too).

Comment: I think bitlocker uses by default 128-bit AES unless you set a flag in the group policy to go to 256 aes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply query the information using `manage-bde.exe`:

```
manage-bde -status C:
```

Just adapt the drive letter to the drive you want to query.

Will return in the line **Encryption Status** what you want to know.

Potential results are:

- AES-CBC 128
- AES-CBC 256
- XTS-AES 128
- XTS-AES 256